# Send Tab key 9 times from keyboard to fill specific textbox in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to send Tab key 9 times from keyboard to fill specific textbox in Selenium webdriver.
Is there any snippet for that?

Comment: Yes, you can loop 9 times and click tab.

Comment: Thanks Maroun, Is there any example for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending **"Tab Keys"** 9 times, you shall **directly locate the element using xpath or css or id**. It's the better thing to do.

However, you can use the below code to press **"Tab Keys"** 9 times using **Robot class**:

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    System.out.println("Tabbed "+i+" time.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Subh for this.I tried this one. Its giving me VK_TAB is not getting resolved.

Comment: Please import KeyEvent class using **import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;** instead of **import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.KeyEvent;**